# Помогите решить задачу на шифрование

Tags: криптография

Если «ркDES» равно 56, а «бв1б» в большинстве случаев равно 8, то чему равно «ксвJ»?

Answer (score 4):

```
27
```

k = 11, c = 3, .. это сумма порядковыйх номеров символов(без регистра) + 1